# How do I locate the source of a segmentation fault? (CS50: recover.c)

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, cs50

I am trying to make a program in c for CS50 that recovers JPG's from a .raw file (reads 512 bytes at a time and sees if it begins with JPG stuff), but it keeps segmentation faulting. How do I tell what the source of the problem is? Thanks guys! (Here's my code for reference)

```
      /**
 * recover.c
 *
 * Computer Science 50
 * Problem Set 4
 *
 * Recovers JPEGs from a forensic image.
 */

 //0xff 0xd8 0xff 0xe0
 //0xff 0xd8 0xff 0xe1

#define BLOCK 512
#define START1END 0xe0
#define START2END 0xe1

#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

//making variables
int found = 0; 
char* title;
FILE* img;
int ifopen = 1;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    //opening file
    FILE* inptr = fopen("card.raw", "r");
    //checking if file opening failed
    if (inptr == NULL)
    {
        return 2;
    }
    //sets the begins or jpgs
    uint8_t checkjpg1[4] = {0xff, 0xd8, 0xff, 0xe0};
    uint8_t checkjpg2[4] = {0xff, 0xd8, 0xff, 0xe1};

    //making buffer
    unsigned char buffer[512];

    //going through the file
    while(fread(&buffer,sizeof(char),BLOCK,inptr) == BLOCK)
    {
         //checking if begin == the possible begin of jpg    
         if ((buffer[0] == checkjpg1[0] && buffer[1] == checkjpg1[1] && buffer[2] == checkjpg1[2]) && 
         (buffer[3] == checkjpg1[3] || buffer[3] == checkjpg2[3]))
         {
            //if a jpg is not open
            if (ifopen == 1)
            {
                //make one
                found+=1;
                sprintf(title,"00%d",found);
                img = fopen(title,"a");
            }
            else//else
            {
                //end the one and open new one
                fclose(img);
                sprintf(title,"00%d",found);
                img = fopen(title,"a");
            }
         }
         else if(img != NULL)
         {
             fwrite(buffer,sizeof(char),BLOCK,img);
         }
    }

    fclose(inptr);
    free(buffer);
}
```

(Sorry about the long overflowing lines!)

Comment: Use a debugger like `GDB`. Alternatively, you can also use `printf` statements here and there to know the place where the seg-fault happens.

Comment: So do I put a printf every so often, and see where one does not print?

Comment: I changed title to "char title[5]", but it a lot of error come up of how it "title[5]" is not a char*.

Comment: also `free(buffer);` is wrong. delete this.

Comment: I also realized that I forgot to put a .jpg after the names.

Comment: So length 5 definitely not enough!

Comment: Yeah, I realized that I needed more (gave me like 10 errors)! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line (and others)

```
sprintf(title,"00%d",found);
```

there is no memory allocated to `title`, it is declared

```
char *title;
```

but that is all.

```
char title[BLOCK];
```

would be better. Incidentally, you don't use `BLOCK` when declaring `buffer` which should be

```
unsigned char buffer[BLOCK];
```

Also, you need another

```
found+=1;
```

before the opening of `img` in the `else` code block.